# Pre select GRUB option from Windows

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, windows

### Background

On my laptop I have grub2 with Ubuntu and Windows10 installed, with Windows10 being the default option. A lot of times I want to boot Ubuntu, but forget to select it in the boot menu and Windows10 boots up, and I need to reboot again.

---

### My question

Is there a way to pre-select the boot option that I want to be select next boot? I've seen multiple questions and answers here about doing so from Ubuntu, but not from Windows. Ideally I want an icon on my desktop that when clicked automatically boots Ubuntu. I wonder if it's even possible to access grub from Windows...

**Remarks**

- Setting Ubuntu as default and if needed booting Windows from there, is a solution, but not the one I am looking for.
- I could also set the grub wait timer to 0, but again, not the solution I am looking for.
- I want to preselect the boot option. .exe for rebooting can be made, but still make me sit around my laptop while its booting.
- I have an Android boot manager (not sure which) on a different pc. That one has .exe file on the desktop which reboots to AndroidOS. That's exactly the behaviour I am looking for.

Thanks in advance to anyone willing to help :D

Answer (score 1):

Not exactly what you're asking for, but it might be a good substitute. This method allows GRUB to remember the last OS that you booted, and use that saved setting for future boots, until you decide to boot a different OS.

`sudo -H gedit /etc/default/grub` # edit grub config file

Change/add the following near the top of the grub file...

```
GRUB_DEFAULT=saved    # change this existing line
GRUB_SAVEDEFAULT=true # add this new line
```

`sudo update-grub` # update grub

Comment: Thanks for your answer! but unfortunately this isnt very helpful.
As I mentioned in my post I've saw some answers and this was one of them.
I use that laptop only for when I am in class, so I don't restart it often but I do need to change OS every other day, or when I want to check something quick on Linux.